# I am using a Dalphi based program on Windows 7 64 bit system and it does not display properly

Tags: windows-7-x64

I use a finanical planning program http://www.visionsystemscorp.com/ProductOverview.aspx?pid=1 that is based on Dalphi programing, 32 bit system.  It worked fine on a XP system but when I got a new system with windows 7, 64 bit and a larger screen I am having trouble with the display.  In some cases the font is over sized and when boxes pop up the box doesn't expand enough to display all of the text (or the text doesn't shrink enough).  I am not a programer, just a user.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the compatibility settings for the program.

To do this you need to locate the program (probably in c:\program files\something-or-other)... once there find the name of the executable file (ends in ".exe").

Right click on it, select properties, and find the compatibility tab. Set the program compatibility for Windows XP.

This *should* fix it.

Comment: This didn't help.  Do you have any other suggestions?  Can I attach a picture so you see the issue?

Comment: If that did not work, try changing the program compatibility to Windows 95.